# StatusBar disappear and flicker on rotation

Tags: ios, statusbar

I've a controller with a 360 video done with GoogleVR. 
When user:

- press the fullscreen function of the video
- rotate a couple of times the device
- come back from fullscreen

-> the statusbar is missing. A black rectangle will be displayed instead

- user come back from the UIViewController from the previous one

-> the statur bar area starts flickering in back and white.

I think the code is useless for this topic, because I've not specific code for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
 override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent // for white statusbar
    }
}
```

In your application, All UIViewController class implement `preferredStatusBarStyle` property .

Now your application display white status bar.